# Insert and use unknown options in GetOptions

Tags: perl

I'm trying to create a script (written in Perl) which gets arguments. The call should look as following:

```
./script [action] --option1 --option2 ... --optionK
```

I use the `GetOptions:Long` module for that. Also I use the `$ARG[0]` in order to get the action. Example:

```
./script report --color black --version 19.4
```

Now I would like to give to the user the power to insert any command he wants (for example it can insert another script with arguments).
I though of doing it like this: user can insert anything he wants at the end (only) of the command-line arguments, for example:

```
./script report --color black --version 19.4 more and more --info 551_5 from --the user
```

I would like to parse this array `@ARGV` and insert the additional information into a variable:

```
$additional = "more and more --info 551_5 from --the user"
```

I found out that after using the `GetOptions`, it will remove those options (not including `$ARGV[0]`) from the `@ARGV` array.
Problem is, I really don't know how to get the additional information from the array. Maybe I should add an additional option, something like this:

```
./script report --color black --version 19.4 --additional more and more --info 551_5 from --the user
```

And get everything in `additional`. But in this way, I have another problem - it will treat `--info` and `--the` as arguments.

How can I solve this issue?

**EDIT**: I saw that `pass_through` is possible to use. But what if user has an option that similar to one of my available options? It could do some problems. Is it possible to handle it just like a string? Also in that way, I'll have to parse `@ARGV` and remove `$ARGV[0]` (the action).

**EDIT-2**: The `--` method will work. But it feels to me as a workaround and not the proper way to solve this issue. There must be a cleaner way to do it. Maybe change to a different module?

Comment: GetOptions can pass through unknown additional options in `@ARGV`, reread https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long for the `pass_through` option.

Comment: If a user uses a similar option to one of your options, how will you know the difference?! Look at the `--` parameter to end option parsing from Getopt::Long

Comment: Re "*But it feels to me as a workaround and not the proper way to solve this issue.*", No, that's specifically what `--` is for. For example, `perl -e'CORE::say for @ARGV' "$FILE"` would fail for a file named `--foo`, so you use `perl -e'CORE::say for @ARGV' -- "$FILE"` instead.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `--` to separate additional arguments: `./script --option1 --option2 -- --userOption1 --userOption2`

https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long#Mixing-command-line-option-with-other-arguments

Answer (score 3):

As @Ujin says `--` will stop processing arguments at that point in the argument list. Another option that you almost got right is the use of --additional. This will work if you wrap the following text in quotes, `'` for unix/linux and `"` for Windows. This will cause the shell to think that all the text after --additional, in the quotes, is one element to be passed into @ARGV. GetOptLong will then correctly see `more and more --info 551_5 from --the user` as the parameter for the --additional option. This makes your command line look like

```
./script report --color black --version 19.4 --additional 'more and more --info 551_5 from --the user'
```